# LWC Array appears to be populated successfully, but the console.log() shows 'undefined' for values of a specific index in the array

Tags: lightning-web-components, array

I have an Apex method that returns to JS an inner class object(which is just an object of 3 fields). When assigning that inner class array to a variable in JS, it appears to be successful. Referencing the first element of the array also appears to be correct, however when I try to reference a specific value for one of the indexes in the array, I get an 'undefined' error in the console.log(). Why would it be undefined? The images below show the array being populated successfully, as well as being able to reference the first element of the array.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for the screenshots. Please also include a description of the screenshot or as much text as you are able from the screenshots as actual text in your post, so that anyone perusing the post with a screenreader will be able to ge tthe gist of what is in the screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.Payload.LoadObject.LoadUpdateObject.LoadConsoleFieldList` is an Array, so you end up creating:

```
loadConsoleFieldList: [
  [ { NodeLabel: 'Special Instructions',
      ConsoleValue: 'Base Cost 4345.0 A...',
      ConsoleFieldLabel: 'Other Instruct...'
    }
  ]
]
```

So the correct value to access would be:

```
this.loadConsoleFieldList[0][0].NodeLabel
```

Instead, I think you meant to concatenate:

```
this.loadConsoleFieldList = [...this.loadConsoleFieldList, ...result.Payload.LoadObject.LoadUpdateObject.LoadConsoleFieldList]
```

Or, alternatively:

```
this.loadConsoleFieldList = this.loadConsoleFieldList.concat(result.Payload.LoadObject.LoadUpdateObject.LoadConsoleFieldList)
```

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you sfdcfox!!